# Setting ResourceQuota for a particular instance type?

Tags: kubernetes, resources, gpu

Is it possible to set a ResourceQuota for a particular instance type/resource rather than a generalized resource type (cpu/memory/gpu)?

For context, in our cluster we care about limiting the number of V100s (a specific GPU type) that are requested. We currently limit the pods that are able to schedule on those nodes by including a taint on all nodes with V100s. Can we also set up a resource quota for e.g. "maximum 32 V100s"?

We have tried setting a generic GPU resource quota but as expected, this applies to all GPU types (T4, etc.) not just the V100s.